# I try to add custom command in DRF not work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: skip-file
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main() -> None:
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault(
        "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "microservice_authentication.settings"
    )
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from management.commands.create_user_and_db import CreateUserAndDbCommand

    # Add your custom management command to the commands dictionary
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "create_user_and_db":
        print("reached")
        commands = {"create_user_and_db": CreateUserAndDbCommand()}
    else:
        commands = {
            "create_user_and_db": CreateUserAndDbCommand(),
            # Add other default Django management commands here, if needed
        }

    print("reach")
    main()
```

My custom command py file

```
# create_user_and_db.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scripts.create_user_and_db import create_database, create_user_and_grant_privileges

class CreateUserAndDbCommand(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Create the database and user role if they do not exist.'
    print("reached")

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("not reached")
        create_database()
        create_user_and_grant_privileges()
```

custom command is not work i get below error

$ python manage.py create_user_and_db
reached
reached
reach
Unknown command: 'create_user_and_db'. Did you mean create_command?
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: Is the name of your command py file called **create_user_and_db.py**?  Is in the directory **management/commands/**?  That might be the problem.